# Angular 6: Skip parent route resolver in child route?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add routes to my app, and I have a parent route with parentResolver and a child route with Child Resolver. When I access the '/parent', the parent resolver kicks in perfectly.

But the problem is, when I access '/parent/child', the parent resolver kicks in again before the child resolver can kick in. I don't want to run the parent resolver when I'm navigating to a child page.

So is there a way to skip the parent resolver when child route is called.
Here's my route config

```
{
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    resolve: {parentData: ParentResolver},
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child',
        component: ChildComponent,
        resolve: {childData: ChildResolver},
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You can define route without using resolver as well.

Comment: I'm using the resolver. For parent route and child route. So if the url is <url>/parent?someparam=somevalue, the parent resolver uses the queryparam.
And same should happen with child resolver.

Comment: thats what i am telling you can do it without using it. i can share routing code where you can define route without using them

Comment: @Exterminator I get that it can be done without. But I need resolvers.

Comment: Could it be, that your `ParentComponent` is not a true parent, if it's behavior changes when a child is present. So maybe you can split it into what is needed generally (parent route without resolver) and what is needed only if no child is present (new route with parentresolver).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
{
    path: 'parent',
    children: [
               {  path : '',
                  pathMatch : 'full',
                  component: ParentComponent,
                  resolve: {parentData: ParentResolver},
                  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange',
               },
               {  path: 'child',
                  component: ChildComponent,
                  resolve: {childData: ChildResolver},
                  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
               }
             ]
}
```

Comment: Tried this. But then Child component overwrites the parent component in the router outlet.

Comment: Check the updated answer. I have added a `pathMatch : 'full'` for the parent path

Answer (score 1):

1. Check in parent resolver what is target path. (or if ActivatedRouteSnapshot has children)

   ```
   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {

     if (route.children.length) {
       // target is some child
     } else {
       // target is parent
     }
   ```

   }
2. Create standalone path: 'parent/child'

Comment: I've tried the first approach but the problem is the child component would overwrite the parent in the router-outlet. I want to child to show in the parent's router-outlet

Comment: Does paren have his own `router-outlet`? I think that no one understood your problem, could you please provide online example? (stackblitz)

Comment: Yeah the parent in this case is a child of app root. which has it's own router outlet. The child component should display in the parent's router outlet. I'll try making a plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

You can create what I call a ResolverGuard, which is a Guard that acts as a Resolver.

```
{
path: 'parent',
component: ParentComponent,
resolve: [ParentResolver], // simply return an Observable<boolean>
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange',
children: [
  {
    path: 'child',
    component: ChildComponent,
    canActivate: [ChildResolverGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
  }
]
```

}

However, this will simply run the child guard before the parent Resolver. The resolver will run regardless, but you can add logic in the ParentResolver to skip it if the child Guard ran.

Checkout https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20805#issuecomment-350106463