# Angular 8 route resolver not canceling route navigation when return EMPTY

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

I'm adding an Angular 8 route resolver to prefetch data. Upon failure (for any reason) I return an EMPTY to cancel the route navigation. However, when I test this, I can step into the catchError block, it shows the toaster, and it returns EMPTY, but the route navigation is not being canceled.  According to all the articles I have read, this should work.  Wanted to know if anybody sees something that I don't.  I have only included the resolve method, since all other configuration is working.

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Country[]> | Observable<never> {
    return this.countryService.getCountries().pipe(      
      mergeMap((countries) => {
        if (countries)
        {
          return of(countries);
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        this.toasterService.pop('error', '', 'There was a problem prefetching the data required to submit a request. If the problem persists, please notify the administrator.');
        return EMPTY;
      }));
  }
```

I expect this code to cancel navigation, per angular documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I went back to the source, angular.io and looked at how the angular team implemented the resolver. They had a piece of code that all other blog posts were missing:

```
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Country[]> | Observable<never> {
    return this.countryService.getCountries().pipe(      
      mergeMap((countries) => {
        if (countries)
        {
          return of(countries);
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/']);//<----- THIS LINE, TO RE-DIRECT TO ANOTHER ROUTE
        return EMPTY;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        this.toasterService.pop('error', '', 'There was a problem prefetching the data required to submit a request. If the problem persists, please notify the administrator.');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);//<----- THIS LINE, TO RE-DIRECT TO ANOTHER ROUTE
        return EMPTY;
      }));
  }
```

So adding the router re-direct seems like an extra step to me.  Especially since it is in direct contradiction that the EMPTY would cancel the navigation.  What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same issue, but what I have noticed that return EMPTY works for child route, not the parent one. I need to explicitly redirect inside parent route resolver but for a child, all works fine. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Are you referring to a scenario like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362416/angular-6-skip-parent-route-resolver-in-child-route) ?

Comment: Yes, I found this is an existing issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24195

Comment: No overload matches this call, anyone was facing that issue doing this?

Comment: Can you give me a bit more info.. maybe the lines of code?

Comment: You're not missing anything it's the migration guide that is wrong imo, I'm facing the same issue